# How to pass <span> inside a string as prop in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, tailwind-css

I am passing a long string to render in a component and I want to change the styling of some words by passing them as span. How can I achieve that in React? I am using Tailwind for CSS. I know I can pass a string array of the spans text, but I am wondering if I can do that passing only 1 string or other value type.

```
<Home description="How can I <span className="text-highlight">highlight</span> 
parts of <span className="text-highlight">this</span> string?" />
```

Component:

```
{description && (
  <p className="text-sm text-text">
    {description}
  </p>
)}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can directly pass JSX as a prop to render.

```
<Home description={<>How can I <span className="text-highlight">highlight</span> 
parts of <span className="text-highlight">this</span> string?</>} />
```

Comment: [Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-8lvai3?file=src%2FApp.jsx)

Comment: Focusing too much on a problem only to forget the basics :). I use Typescript, I guess I should use it as ReactNode and use this `description={<></>}` for empty, right?

Comment: @Richard Yes, that is correct. You can also pass `null`, `false`, or `undefined` for empty.

Answer (score -1):

I believe what you are looking for is https://react.dev/reference/react-dom/components/common#dangerously-setting-the-inner-html.

You will want to do something like the following within your `Home` component.

```
export default function Home({ description }) {
  return (
    {description && (
      <p className="text-sm text-text">
        <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: description }} />
      </p>
    )}
  )
}
```

Using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` as its name suggests is dangerous to use. Only use on trusted or sanitized values. I would recommend reading more about this in the link.

**EDIT**: After seeing the accepted answer, I realized I did not understand the question being asked. This looks like a good use case for the `children` property.

```
export default function Home({ children }) {
  return (
    {children && (
      <p className="text-sm text-text">
        {children}
      </p>
    )}
  )
}
```

You can then pass those values in as such

```
function SomeOtherComponent() {
  <Home>
    How can I <span className="text-highlight">highlight</span> 
    parts of <span className="text-highlight">this</span> string?
  </Home>
}
```